# If a file exists, copy another file, but don't overwrite

Tags: bash

Given the following code:

```
for d in ./Event_*/; do
set -- "$d/"*.mcp
if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    # there is at least one .mcp file in $d
    cp -rp -v -- "$d/KNYN.BHZ" ./newdir/
fi
done
```

What I want to do is, for every directory in ./Event_*/, if there is a file *.mcp that exists, copy the file KNYN.BHZ to the new directory.  Since all of the file names KNYN.BHZ are the same, how do I copy all KNYN.BHZ files without them overwriting?  As my code stands now, if I run it, the output is only one file KNYN.BHZ.

Comment: You have to rename the files somehow.

Comment: I understand that.  Is there a way to add a counter, then within /newdir/output the new KNYN.BHZ files to a new directory named after that counter?

Comment: Why don't you rename them by prepending the source directory, for example, `cp -rp -v -- "$d/KNYN.BHZ" ./newdir/$d_KNYN.BHZ`?

Comment: You can do anything you can think of. You just need to decide what that renaming wants to be.

Comment: Ideally, I'd want to rename the files in ./newdir/ to KNYN.BHZ_1, KNYN.BHZ_2, ... KNYN.BHZ_n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give each file an unique name. For example, you could suffix the directory name (or just the part `*` stands for):

```
for d in ./Event_*/; do
set -- "$d/"*.mcp
if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    cp -rp -v -- "$d/KNYN.BHZ" "./newdir/KNYN.`echo $d | sed 's/[\.\/]//g;s/Event_//:'`.BHZ"
fi
done
```

Thus `Event_123/KNYN.BHZ` would become `./newdir/KNYN-123.BHZ`.

Or you might use a counter:

```
i=0;
for d in ./Event_*/; do
set -- "$d/"*.mcp
if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    cp -rp -v -- "$d/KNYN.BHZ" "./newdir/KNYN-$((++i)).BHZ"
fi
done
```

Thus `Event_123/KNYN.BHZ` would become `./newdir/KNYN-4.BHZ` (or whatever-manieth directory with a `mcp` it is).

The latter solution is simpler, whereas the former retains the association to the original folder (which might be important if you do that repeatedly - though of course you'd need different folders or add a date:

```
for d in ./Event_*/; do
set -- "$d/"*.mcp
if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    cp -rp -v -- "$d/KNYN.BHZ" "./newdir/KNYN.`echo $d | sed 's/[\.\/]//g;s/Event_//:'`_`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`.BHZ"
fi
done
```

Which yields `./newdir/KNYN-123_2015-05-21.BHZ` (or move it to the directory to get `./2015-05-21/KNYN-123.BHZ`).

Comment: I am a big fan of this counter idea -- I just didn't know how to implement it!  Thank you for this helpful response.

Comment: If I wanted to add the MCP file name to the output, for example KNYN.blah.mcp.BHZ, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNU CoreUtils cp (which is very likely), there's a [`--backup`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Backup-options.html#Backup-options) option to `cp`. I think the `numbered` method will be a good place to start, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RANDOM` variable.

```
for d in ./Event_*/; do
set -- "$d/"*.mcp
if [ -e "$1" ]; then
    # there is at least one .mcp file in $d
    cp -rp -v -- "$d/KNYN.BHZ" ./newdir/KNYN_${RANDOM}.BHZ
fi
done
```

Comment: Hi Rahul,  Thanks for the response.  While this is a good answer and it works, the random numbers suffix isn't necessary for what I'm doing -- i'd rather use numbers as a suffix as they reference to the counter.  Thanks, though!

Comment: @user78872 . Thanks. Yes, I got that after reading your comments. The counter is a  good idea. I guess we both posted the answer at the same time :).